# Hiding scanner progress bar window

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, events, hook

I'm making an application that needs to scan an image, from a scanner.

I've based my application on this project
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/171666/Twain-for-WPF-Applications-Look-Ma-No-Handles
and the scanning part works excelently.

But here is my problem: I need to make the scan without showing any window to the user.

The above project allows me not to to display the scanner configuration option screen to the user,
but it still displays the progress bar.

The progress bar shows up (and the scan begins) when I call

```
DSixfer(
    appid,
    srcds,
    TwDG.Image,
    TwDAT.ImageNativeXfer,
    TwMSG.Get,
    ref hbitmap );

[DllImport("twain_32.dll", EntryPoint="#1")]
private static extern TwRC DSixfer( [In, Out] TwIdentity origin, [In] TwIdentity dest, TwDG dg, TwDAT dat, TwMSG msg, ref IntPtr hbitmap );
```

I searched throughout all the parameters but was unable to see any that could disable the progress bar.

So I decided to capture the event of the progress bar window being created, and hide it (is there any better way?) but the event isn't being caught.

First I create a temporary window, because my application will be a windows service and also because TWAIN requires a window handle to which it associates the progress bar.

This is my code

```
HookProc WindowCreationProcedure = new HookProc(WindowCreationHookProc);

int hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL,
        WindowCreationProcedure,
        (IntPtr)0,
        AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()
        );

System.Windows.Window tmpWindow = new System.Windows.Window();
tmpWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;  //So that the window isn't showed
tmpWindow.Show();
```

I receive the event of my tmpWindow being created but not the progress bar. What am I missing here?

***EDIT : *** Had forgotten to add my hook function in this post

```
private const int WH_SHELL = 10;
private const int HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED = 1;

public static int WindowCreationHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WINDOW CREATED");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in windows vista & up, windows services are forbidden from interacting with desktop (this might be the reason you're not receiving hook event). To isolate the problem try performing this first from an application which is not a service see if you receive the hook there. If that's the case you could launch a desktop application from service which could handle supression of progress bar.

Comment: All the tests that I made are from a windows form application just because of that ;)

Comment: Twain is grossly outdated on Windows.  You'll need to move up to WIA (Windows Image Acquisition).  Google away.

Comment: I cannot use WIA because my application needs to handle old scanners that don't support WIA

Comment: Have you tried to put your window outside the desktop boundary? Something like window.Left = -10000; window.Top = -10000; If the ProgressBar is displayed relative to its parent, it will not be visible.

Comment: Already tried that :(
The progress bar positioning is Center Screen

Comment: Can you include a screen shot of the progress bar? Are you sure the progress is a window and not being directly drawn and/or is this windows coming from the scanner's driver?

Answer (score 1):

Why to do all these things when the ready-made capability of Twain is available.

Just set `CAP_INDICATORS` value to false and that's it.  The hex value for it is: `0x100b`.

Answer (score 0):

To stop TWAIN from popping up it's interface, you need to send the message `DG_CONTROL / DAT_USERINTERFACE / MSG_ENABLEDS` with ShowUI = FALSE and ModalUI = FALSE. Here is [some example code](https://github.com/jeske/twaindotnet/blob/incremental_scanning/src/TwainDotNet/DataSource.cs#L410).

It's also possible to get incremental status during a scan, instead of being blocked for the whole scan. Instead of using ImageNativeXfer, you use Memory Block Transfers, described starting on page 4-20 of the [Twain Spec](http://www.twain.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/TWAIN-2.4-Specification.pdf). You can see a [example code here](https://github.com/jeske/twaindotnet/blob/incremental_scanning/src/TwainDotNet/DataSourceManager.cs#L168).